# Access motion server from the internet

Tags: server, motion

I encountred an issue with motion server for raspberry pi. I use the PiCam with motion-mmal special build by dozencrows.

I can access to my nginx server from internet for my rails app on the RPI. But it's impossible for motion server. I opened the right ports on my router (same as in motion.conf file).

I suspect a problem with hosts names.

i guess nginx acces from internet is mapped by router to localhost (127.0.0.1), but motion server seems to use raspberrypi host name (127.0.1.1).

Did anybody can help me to setup the motion server to be accessible from internet ?

thanks !

Comment: Do you have port forwarding configured in router?

Comment: as @Fildor says make sure the port forwarding is setup on the router. 127.0.0.1 is a non routable address and I doubt your DHCP has assigned 127.0.1.1. The router should have a routing table(live) that you can find the addressable ip address of the Pi make sure all those are correct on the router and it will work.

Comment: Of course every ports are forwarded: ssh access, vnc access work even my rails server.
But as i said, it looks that the issue is on the hosts name on the raspberrypi.
obviously all services like vncserver, nginx, ssh pass by the local ip 127.0.0.1 (name: localhost), while motion started its server on 127.0.1.1 (name: raspberrypi), which is the cause the problem, and why i can't access

Comment: the internet -> my router (myddnsname.ddns.net) -> localhost (127.0.0.1) for most services
but for motion
the internet -> my router (myddnsname.ddns.net) -> raspberrypi (127.0.1.1)